# how to convert object list in python to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a class `event`.

```
class event:
    def __init__(self,Day,Month,Name,Location,Time):
        self.Day = Day
        self.Month = Month
        self.Name= Name
        self.Location= Location
        self.Time = Time
```

Suppose I have a list `eventlist` with instances of `event`. How do I get a dataframe from the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give the `DataFrame` constructor a list of dicts, each dict will be interpreted as a record (row).

```
>>> events = [event(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), event(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)]                                                                    
>>> pd.DataFrame([vars(e) for e in events])                                                                                  
    Day  Location  Month  Name  Time
0    1         4      2     3     5
1    6         9      7     8    10
```

You can specify a deterministic column order by supplying the `columns` keyword-argument.